# When creating an Airflow custom operator, do I need to overwrite the constructor if I don't add any arguments?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I'm trying to create a custom FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator to allow it to transfer files more than 2GB using chunks, cause the regular one doesn't allow this.
So far I've used a Python Operator and called this function:

```
def upload_to_gcs(**kwargs):
    chunk_size = 128 * 1024 * 1024
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(kwargs['bucket'])
    blob = bucket.blob(gcs_folder + kwargs['file'] + kwargs['date'] + '.csv', chunk_size=chunk_size)
    blob.upload_from_filename(kwargs['file'] + '.csv')
```

but first I don't know to specify the conn_id using this method, and second I'd like to have a more "Airflow-ish" way to do this.

So I've looked at the regular FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator code, and it uses the GoogleCloudStorageHook to specify the conn_id, but looking at the Gcs hook code it doesn't seem like I can specify a chunk_size parameter.

So first question:

When writing  my custom operator code, do I need to overwrite the constructor even if I don't add any argument to it?

Second question:

How should I write my execute function to make it work like my function above but specifying the conn_id using the self.google_cloud_storage_conn_id?

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your first question, you only need to specify the arguments specific to your operator, and use @apply_defaults decorator function to fill unspecified arguments with default_args. This is documented on the [Creating a custom Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator) page.

Secondly, you can refer to self in the self.google_cloud_storage_conn_id statement in you execute code; an example is provided on the same page:

```
 def execute(self, context):
        message = "Hello {}".format(self.name)
        print(message)
        return message
```

Comment: Hi - but how would you extend the FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator in this case? Instead of the BaseOperator, as suggested by Airflow?